# loading excel 2007 (xlsx) on server

Tags: asp.net

After publishing my asp.net web application on my hosting, I for this problem:

```
Error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on
the local machine.
```

This is my connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(fileName) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
```

After searching on Google, I found that my hosting server should install:  `Microsoft office Access database engine 2007` @ http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23734

I contact them but they said it is not allowed to install that component on their server...

Is there a way to read excel 2007 file on my server without installing that component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, it should be excel 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read OpenXML format Excel documents using [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124). It's much easier to use it via [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: so, using openXML to read excel 2007 files and using ClosedXML to write excel 2007 files, correct?

Comment: ClosedXML is just a nice wrapper for OpenXML. You can use ClosedXML for both reading and writing Excel files, but it required OpenXML dll to be present on the system (since it uses it internally for processing files).

Comment: I just found this one http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/ without openXML dependency...

Comment: You can operate directly on OpenXML files (since it's just XML), but you a risking compatibility and usually have very limited feature set.